# Wordpress site htaccess not redirecting to https when manually entering URL starting with http

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've made changes to my htaccess file on my WordPress site to redirect traffic from http to https.

Most cases it works fine and redirects traffic to https, but some cases it doesn't.

For example, if I try access home page with http in address it redirects to https, but if I try and access another page on the site with http in URL it stays on http:

- http: //example.com redirects fine to https: //example.com
- http: //example.com/page stays on http: //example.com/page

Current htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've tried numerous answers in other question, what else can I try?

Comment: I know you are trying to do this manually but I'd suggest this plugin that automates this for you https://wordpress.org/plugins/https-redirection/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: using this code you are still facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes, same issue

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the following at the bottom? What happens when you remove this? I think this may be conflicting with RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off at the top. What happens when you remove this...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've removed that line. It didn't fix my https issue, but it obviously wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

It will work for www and https

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your site address in Settings:
[image]

and add the code below at the top of WordPress’ .htaccess file.

1. RewriteEngine on
2. RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC,OR]
3. RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
4. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: My settings are changed already. Do those lines just remove the www. ? Cause my current htaccess already does that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the fix was really simple... Just be sure to put the https redirection BEFORE the original rewrite code of Wordpress...

Exemple :

```html
# Redirection code (redirect no www to www and http to https)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```